# SQL Server Join Query results in error

Tags: sql-server

```
SELECT 
    Bus.BusNumber,Stop.StopName, Bus_time.Time 
FROM 
    Stop 
INNER JOIN 
    Bus_time ON Stop.Stop_id = Bus_time.Stop_id 
INNER JOIN 
    Bus ON Bus_time.Bus_id = Bus.Bus_id 
WHERE
    (Bus_time.Bus_id = (SELECT DISTINCT bus_id FROM Bus_time t1 
                        WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Bus_time 
                                      WHERE Stop_id = '3' 
                                        AND bus_id = t1.Bus_id) 
                          AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Bus_time 
                                      WHERE Stop_id = '1' 
                                        AND bus_id = t1.Bus_id))) 
    AND (Stop.Stop_id = '1')
```

This is my query and error is

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer, thanks for helping.

```
SELECT DISTINCT bus.busnumber, 
                stop.stopname, 
                bus_time.time 
FROM   stop 
       INNER JOIN bus_time 
               ON stop.stop_id = bus_time.stop_id 
       INNER JOIN bus 
               ON bus_time.bus_id = bus.bus_id 
       INNER JOIN bus_time t1 
               ON bus_time.bus_id = t1.bus_id 
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT * 
               FROM   bus_time 
               WHERE  stop_id = '3' 
                      AND bus_id = t1.bus_id) 
       AND EXISTS (SELECT * 
                   FROM   bus_time 
                   WHERE  stop_id = '1' 
                          AND bus_id = t1.bus_id) 
       AND ( stop.stop_id = '3' )
```

Answer (score 0):

This part of your query may return more than one value, which is not compatible with `=` operator.

```
WHERE ( bus_time.bus_id = (SELECT DISTINCT bus_id 
                           FROM   bus_time t1
```

so add `top 1` to your query like this..

```
SELECT bus.busnumber, 
       stop.stopname, 
       bus_time.time 
FROM   stop 
       INNER JOIN bus_time 
               ON stop.stop_id = bus_time.stop_id 
       INNER JOIN bus 
               ON bus_time.bus_id = bus.bus_id 
WHERE ( bus_time.bus_id = (SELECT top 1 bus_id 
                           FROM   bus_time t1 
                           WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT * 
                                          FROM   bus_time 
                                          WHERE  stop_id = '3' 
                                                 AND bus_id = t1.bus_id) 
                                  AND EXISTS (SELECT * 
                                              FROM   bus_time 
                                              WHERE  stop_id = '1' 
                                                     AND bus_id = t1.bus_id)) ) 
      AND ( stop.stop_id = '1' )
```

As lad2025 mentioned in the comment, though the above code fixes the error, you need to reconsider your approach. If you expect more than one value returned from subquery use `IN`.

Comment: `TOP 1` just suppress error and bus_id will be random. OP should use `IN` or rethink his whole query.

Comment: @lad2025 : I completely agree.